# How to Stop WordPress ping backs?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am beginner in WordPress. I had installed WordPress But i found there are so many ping backs shows on dashboard. My question is i want to remove all of the ping backs that are useless for me.

Answer (score 1):

As Sagar, link it in his answer, you can do it with code:

```
<?php
add_filter('wp_headers', function($headers, $wp_query){
    if(isset($headers['X-Pingback'])){
        unset($headers['X-Pingback']);
    }
    return $headers;
}, 11, 2);
add_filter('pre_option_enable_xmlrpc', function($state){
    return '0';
});
add_action('wp', function(){
    remove_action('wp_head', 'rsd_link');
}, 9);
add_filter('bloginfo_url', function($output, $property){
    return ($property == 'pingback_url') ? null : $output;
}, 11, 2);
add_action('xmlrpc_call', function($method){
    if($method != 'pingback.ping') return;
    wp_die(
        'Pingback functionality is disabled on this Blog.',
        'Pingback Disabled!',
        array('response' => 403)
    );
});
?>
```

Put that in your **function.php** file.

Or you can do it with [a simple plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-xml-rpc-pingback/) if you don't want to code.